# How to match two observation values in a data frame and assign values in a third column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Before I begin explaining, my data is super messy and I am not an advanced programmer, so bear with me.

I have a large data frame with two columns containing data on each row and one column containing spread data and NA's. I want to identify a value in the NA column, using the two other columns, and assign that value to the other rows in the NA column that have the matching other two columns.

To explain what I mean I have created a small sample code with a data frame 270 x 3:

```
Sample Code:

year <-c()
for (i in 1988:1990){
  y1 <- i %>% rep(30)
  year <- c(year, y1)
}

year <- year %>% rep(3)

stock <- c()
for (i in 1:18) {
  s1 <- i %>% rep(15)
  stock<- c(stock, s1)
}

df <- data.frame(year,stock)
df$group <- NA

df$group[c(24, 130, 160, 212)] <- 11
df$group[c(60, 88, 140, 240)] <- 12
df$group[c(2, 72, 100, 183)] <- 13
df$group[c(16, 47, 203, 262)] <- 14
```

I have years and stocks data in every row, but the group is random. The years can be repeated because they are years of a collection of monthly dates and different stocks on the same dates.

I want to identify the group number of a certain row and see if that stock "persists" 12 months by having the same yearly value for i + 11 rows. I then want to assign the value of the stock's group in row i to i:(i+11). In other words, I want to see if the stock in row i and row i+11 is the same stock and the year is the same in row i and i+11

I tried to overcome this problem by only looking at the rows where we have data and create if-else conditions inside a for loop:

```
identifier <- which(!is.na(df$group))

for (i in identifier) {
  if (df$stock[i] == df$stock[i + 11]) {
    df$group[(i+1):(i+11)] <- df$group[i]
  } else {
    df$group[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

I have two problems (that I have found so far) with the code:

1. It does not look at all 12 values from i to i+11, so it can cause
   overlapping groups to become NA and assign false groups to certain
   stocks and periods
2. My original data frame consist of >3m observations and the for loop takes more than 30 minutes to run.

My sample code does not fully represent my original data set. Some stocks exist for 15 years and some 20 months. The stocks can also change group from year to year.

Here is an example of the error and how I want it to look:

```
df$group[24] # is NA, but the surrounding values are not
df$group[16:27] 

# They should be NA, in this example
df$group[16:27] <- NA
df$group[262] <-NA # also identified error

# I then want to remove the NA's and get a clean data set containing only stocks with assigned groups
df <- df[-which(is.na(df$group)),]
df
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient?

- Ways I can structure the data better?
- More efficiently look for values in a column and then assign it to the other rows?

Comment: Very nice that you have included some sample code for reproducability. Few new users do that. Would be even nice if you showed e.g. the first five rows of the dataframe and a dataframe with your desired outcome so that a glance is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @coffeinjunky! I added a new code snippet, hope it helps explain

Comment: To start with, R isn't really a loop-friendly languange. I would probably begin with something like `df %>% mutate(stock_ly = lag(stock, 11), persist = stock==stock_ly)` and take it from there.

Comment: That's very clever, then I know which rows are usable. And from there identify the rows `which(!is.na(df$group) & df$persist == TRUE)`?

Comment: Managed to work through the data set (original data) using the mutate function. New loop takes less than 1 second! Thanks @coffeinjunky